# Rerender select element with a default option from parent state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `select` component, which calls a callback given by a parent component to change a state maintained by the parent. This callback is called when an `option` is selected in the component. This `select` component disappears (rendering `null` instead of the component) after some scrolling interaction. The problem is, when the `select` component is allowed to reappear, it defaults to its first option, instead of the  `state` from the parent.

I have already passed the state down to the component. I'm stuck with using the state to make an `option` tag of the component be selected by default once it reappears.

Here is the `select` component:

```
export default function Child({onStateChange, parentState}) {

  return (
    <div
      ...
      onChange={(e) => props.onStateChange(selectEventToString(e))}
    >
      <select>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
        ...
  );
}
```

Here  is the parent component:

```
export default function Parent() {
  const [maintainedState, setMaintainedState] = useState("initial state");

  function handleStateChange(newValue) {
    setMaintainedState(newValue);
  }

  return (
    <div className="one-town">
      <Child parentState={maintainedState} onStateChange={handleStateChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
`
``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this, put your stat in value to be selected and on change select change state

const Child = ({ onStateChange, parentState }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <select value={parentState} onChange={e => onStateChange(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [maintainedState, setMaintainedState] = useState('b');

  function handleStateChange(newValue) {
    setMaintainedState(newValue);
  }

  return (
    <div className="one-town">
      <Child parentState={maintainedState} onStateChange={handleStateChange} />
    </div>
  );
};
```